# Getting loans from Foreign banks

Tags: india, loans, foreign-exchange, hedge-funds

The interest on bank loans is 10% in India. Instead, is it possible to get loans from USA banks to India at 3.3-4% for a project ?
Is this what is called hedging or hedge funds ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get a loan from foreign banks in USD. It carries currency risks. Generally done by large companies.

> Is this what is called hedging or hedge funds ?

hedging is very different concept. The [investopedia article](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hedge.asp) is a good starting point

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get foreign loans at lower interest rates. This can become good or bad based on the currency fluctuation. Market participants likes to pretend this is all "priced in" in such a way that nobody can benefit from taking advantage of lower interest rates in a different currency, but there are many ways to take advantage of this, and many do.

This has nothing to do with hedging or hedge funds, aside from the fact that many hedge funds too engage in cross currency borrowing.